# How to get the right output for this turtle function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I have a logic error for this function. I need to write a function called spikes() that draw
lines radiating from a common starting point. It takes three parameters, which are 
numLines for number of lines to draw, lengthIncr for the length of the first line and
increase in length of the successive lines, and angle that goes clockwise and it is the angle between successive lines. I use the latest version of Python (3.4.2). Also, the function spides must repeatedly call the function drawLine(). I think the error is the call function for drawLine in the function spikes, but I don't know how to fix it. The output I get is a very long curve line that goes downward forever. The real output I should get is spikes. Here is the code:

```
#Question 14 Part a-

import turtle
s = turtle.Screen()
t = turtle.Turtle()

def drawLine(t, length): 
    t.pendown()
    t.forward(length)
    t.penup()


length = 50
drawLine(t, length)

#Question 14 Part b-

def spikes(numLines, lengthIncr, angle):
    for i in range(numLines):
        drawLine(t, lengthIncr * i)
        t.right(angle)

print(spikes(36, 25, 5))

#Output I should get: '''
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to return to your origin before drawing each spike?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert on `turtle`, but is this what you're looking for?

```
import turtle
s = turtle.Screen()
t = turtle.Turtle()

def drawLine(t, length): 
    t.pendown()
    t.forward(length)
    t.penup()

def there_and_back(t, length):
    drawLine(t, length)
    t.penup()
    t.right(180)
    t.forward(length)
    t.right(180)
    t.pendown()

length = 50

#Question 14 Part b-

def spikes(numLines, lengthIncr, angle):
    for i in range(numLines):
        length = lengthIncr * i
        there_and_back(t, length)
        t.right(angle)

print(spikes(36, 25, 5))
```

Comment: What about putting the "return to originating point" functionality inside the drawline function?  It would even become useful for something, and one can have control about drawing or not on the way back.